# X wa Y ga suki desu

Tags: grammar

I read several times that an expression such as "X wa Y ga suki desu", where say both X and Y are people, is inherently ambiguous and can be understood as either "X likes Y" or "Y likes X", according to the context.

If that's correct, then I'm wondering how that ambiguity is "felt" grammatically in terms of the meaning of suki. As I understand it, suki is a na-adjective that simply means "liked" or "preferred". If "X wa Y ga suki desu" is ambiguous, is "suki-na X" also ambiguous? Can it mean not only "X that is liked" but also "liked by X"?

Comment: Could you show a reference that states "X wa Y ga suki desu" means "Y likes X"? As a native Japanese speaker, I always understand "X wa Y ga suki desu" as "X likes Y", where both X and Y are people.

Comment: Have a look at these other posts and see if they help: [How do adjectives work in relative clauses?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39049/542) and [私は猫が好き and 猫は私が好き](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17857/542)

Answer (score 2):

"X wa Y ga suki desu" **always** means "X likes Y" unless you're in a very special context.

It's actually theoretically possible that this effectively means "Y likes X" in a certain special context where *ga* works as the exhaustive-listing marker (See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010) for exhaustive-lisging *ga*):

> **A**: I know either Y or Z likes X. Which? Who likes X?
>   **B**: X wa Y ga suki desu. (It's Y who likes X.)

B's answer would be pronounced with a different intonation from the normal "X wa Y ga suki desu".

Nevertheless, people will rarely make a question like this, and I don't know if this really is what you have read. And even when people make such a question, I doubt you would ever hear an answer like this actually used in real life. There is a better, clearer way to put this. This answer would be far more natural when said like this:

> **B**: [X no koto](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/5010) wa Y ga suki desu. (It's Y who likes X.)

---

A similar expression can also be ambiguous when it forms a relative clause. I think these pages answers your question about "suki-na X":

- [Ambiguity in meaning of sentences with a noun qualifed by an adjective with が particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23644/5010)
- [が in subordinate clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30171/5010)

Comment: I don't find it "rare" that we use ambiguous forms like "X ga suki-na no wa Y da" and leave it to the context which it means.